# the response of GMSGeocoder reverseGeocodeCoordinate is not localized suddenly

Tags: google-maps-sdk-ios

Since of yesterday, the response of reverseGeocodeCoordinate is always english regardless of default language of iPhone.

GMSReverseGeocodeResponse should be localized string which depends on iPhone language setting.

```
[[GMSGeocoder geocoder] reverseGeocodeCoordinate:coord completionHandler:^(GMSReverseGeocodeResponse* response, NSError* error) {
    GMSAddress *address = [response firstResult];
    // address always english!! regardless of change of default language on iPhone settings
}
```

I have used this API more than 1 years and it worked great. We have many Japanese, Korean, Chinese users. and they complain that the address is English suddenly.

Answer (score 2):

It was a problem with the Google APIs. It's been fixed, everything should be fine now if it was working before.

Answer (score 0):

It seems no official answer at this moment. And [CLGeocoder](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/clgeocoder) seems to be the workaround at this moment...